# Powershell WebScraping and Terminating Exception Handling

Tags: powershell, exception, web-scraping, nullreferenceexception

I'm using powershell to check several different sites for data. If the site has no data for today, it will throw a NullReferenceException. I'd like for the script to output a message that there is no data, then continue on to the other sites without halting.

In Java, I can simply just try/catch/finally, but Powershell isn't acting as nicely.

```
  try {

      $webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://###.##.###.##:####/abcd.aspx?"

   } catch [System.NullReferenceException]{

           Write-Host "There is no data"

   }
```

The full error displays in console, and the Write-Host never actually appears.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
   $webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://host/link" -erroraction stop
}
catch [System.NullReferenceException]{
       Write-Host "There is no data" 
}
```

Powershell distinguishes between terminating and non terminating errors, for catch to work, you need the error to be terminating. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/

UPD: to get the type of exception, after you get the error just do:
`$Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName`
and you use that to catch that specific error after

to continue on specific error with invoke-webrequest you can do something like this:

```
try { Invoke-WebRequest "url" }
catch { $req = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__}
if ($req -neq 404) { do stuff }
```

Comment: I used that line you added in the update to check the error type. Sure enough the NRE was actually a WebException. So if stop halts the program, i could change it to silently continue if i need to loop through an array of URI's?

Comment: usually yes, but not with invoke-webrequest

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the exception may not be a Null Reference exception. I Initially thought it to be a Non-Terminating error, but invoke-webrequest throws a terminating error.

In this case, you may simply try (without catching a specific exception type)

**--Edited Per OP Comments--**

```
try 
{
Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://doc/abcd.aspx?" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch 
{    
    if($_.Exception.GetType().FullName -eq "YouranticipatedException") 
    {
        Write-Host ("Exception occured in Invoke-WebRequest.")
        # You can also get the response code thru "$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__" if there is response to your webrequest 
    }
```

Comment: You were correct - It was not a NRE. I do not believe, however, that blindly eating the exception is the most appropriate move. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Then handle with appropriate exception type or simply use $_.Exception.GetType().FullName to get exception information.